# build-impl.xml:1050: The module has not been deployed error, when running a java springs web project + netbeans

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, netbeans

I have netbeans ide 8.1 in windows and i created a java web application with springs f/w in it. Glassfish server is also properly installed. When i run it, it always shows the following error:

```
C:\\xyz\abc\project1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1050: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

When i click on the link, it goes to following line in build-impl.xml

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

What is wrong here and how do i see the server logs?

Comment: Have you got solution for this issue?